# TabLayout ViewPager2 work with Fragment how to make fragment init load when select Tab

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I have three `Fragment`s

1. HomeFragment
2. DiscFrament
3. MeFragment

work with ViewPager2 and TabLayout set smoothScroll true use defalut, but lazy loading not working

```
 TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) {
     tab, position ->
        tab.text = position.toString() 
            }.attach()
```

and what I need is

1. I need smoothScroll the tab Indicator
2. Lazy loading Fragment when I scroll the page or Select Tab the Fragment data load view show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                tab?:return
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.position, false)
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }

        })
```

the most important code is `viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.position, false)` to override TabLayoutMediator addOnTabSelectedListener, so that it can be smooth scroll but also can lazy load